# Interface Service gives null exception error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have created an Interface called ILoginService and a Class implementing this service called LoginService. I am passing a stored Procedure through this service that returns a Scalar value.

The problem is that ILoginService object returns a null value giving  Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error

Please help with this code is as follows:

LoginService Code

```
 public partial class LoginService : ILoginService
{

    TimesheetsManagementEntities TimesheetDatabase = new TimesheetsManagementEntities();

    private readonly ILoginService _LoginService;
    object UserAutheticationStatusObject;

    int UserAutheticationStatusCode;

    public LoginService(ILoginService LoginService) {


        _LoginService = LoginService;
    }


    public int UserAuthetication(string EmailId, string LoginPassword)
    {
        using (TimesheetDatabase) {
             TimesheetDatabase.Database.Connection.Open();
             var command = TimesheetDatabase.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
             command.CommandText = "dbo.UserLoginAuthentication";
             command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             UserAutheticationStatusObject = (command.ExecuteScalar());

        }

        UserAutheticationStatusCode = (int)UserAutheticationStatusObject;

            return UserAutheticationStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Controller code

```
 public class AccountsController : Controller
{

    private readonly ILoginService _LoginService;

    int UserAuthenticationStatus;




    public AccountsController(ILoginService LoginService) {

        _LoginService = LoginService;

    }


    public AccountsController() { }



    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        LoginViewModel LoginModel = new LoginViewModel();

      UserAuthenticationStatus = _LoginService.UserAuthetication(LoginModel.EmailId, LoginModel.LoginPassword);



        return View(LoginModel);
    }
}
```

ViewModel Code

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seems wrong with this, there's no parameterless constructor for your `LoginService` class, and the only constructor available require a same type `LoginService` object  ... I just don't see how this could work ...

Also, your `ILoginService` seems to be injected into your `AccountController`, make sure your DependencyInjection container can instanciate your `ILoginService` class properly.

Comment: @nobisvert i  am new to MVC concepts , i guess i don't know how the parameterless constructor works can please explain me